# if-statement adjusts multiple dictionary key values even though statement only specifies one key

Tags: python, dictionary, if-statement, boolean

So I'm making a little text based RPG as a personal project. I have a dictionary which maps out the game locations with nested dictionaries - for example:

```
zonemap = {
    "a1": {ZONENAME: "somename", DESCRIPTION: "somedescription", SOLVED: False, SEARCHED: False},
    "a2": {ZONENAME: "somename", DESCRIPTION: "somedescription", SOLVED: False, SEARCHED: False},
    "c3": {ZONENAME: "somename", DESCRIPTION: "somedescription", SOLVED: False, SEARCHED: False}
    #so on for all game locations
    }
```

The SOLVED key stores a boolean that tells us if the area has been completed. When the below function is called and updates the `SEARCHED` key, it is also updating the `SOLVED` key. The print statements return `True` for both keys but it should only update `SEARCHED`

```
def search_zone():
    if zonemap[myPlayer.location][SEARCHED] == False:
        zonemap[myPlayer.location][SEARCHED] = True #this line is the trouble maker
        for key in zonemap.keys():
            print('SOLVED', zonemap[key][SOLVED])
            print('SEARCHED', zonemap[key][SEARCHED])
```

Why would `zonemap[myPlayer.location][SEARCHED] = True` update two keys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed your code a bit so it's easy to debug. But it seems to be working for me under these test conditions:

```
ZONENAME = "ZONENAME"
DESCRIPTION = "DESCRITPTION"
SOLVED = "SOLVED"
SEARCHED = "SEARCHED"


zonemap = {
    "a1": {ZONENAME: "somename", DESCRIPTION: "somedescription", SOLVED: False, SEARCHED: False},
    "a2": {ZONENAME: "somename", DESCRIPTION: "somedescription", SOLVED: False, SEARCHED: False},
    "c3": {ZONENAME: "somename", DESCRIPTION: "somedescription", SOLVED: False, SEARCHED: False}
    #so on for all game locations
    }

def search_zone(location):
    if zonemap[location][SEARCHED] == False:
        zonemap[location][SEARCHED] = True
        for key in zonemap.keys():
            print(f'SOLVED {key}', zonemap[key][SOLVED])
            print(f'SEARCHED {key}', zonemap[key][SEARCHED])

search_zone("a1")
```

output:

```
SOLVED a1 False
SEARCHED a1 True
SOLVED a2 False
SEARCHED a2 False
SOLVED c3 False
SEARCHED c3 False
```

It only updates `SEARCHED` and not `SOLVED`

Comment: Oh my god thank you - it was so simple. When I created the global variables for ```SEARCHED``` and ```SOLVED``` I assigned True and False values. Changing them to the below fixed the issue! 

```SOLVED = "SOLVED"```

Any idea why that would cause both to update?

Comment: I'm not too sure, to my knowledge that shouldn't cause a problem. Let me know if you find out what was the bug!